# Get favicon from chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, favicon

Some site have updated `favicon.ico` and file served by old url gives the new icon.

But Chrome in most of tabs still shows the old icon. How can I get the old icon and save it as an image?

Some time ago the was `chrome://cache/` url allowing to save cached files, but now it is removed from Chrome. Is there any replacement?

Comment: For FF this path may help: `AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile-name>.default\jumpListCache`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](//superuser.com/a/1260043/724113) favicons are stored in file

```
win:   %LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Favicons
mac:   ${user.home}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Favicons
```

This file is sqlite database and you can copy and open it using [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

The query to get icons is

```sql
select f.url, b.*
from favicons f inner join favicon_bitmaps b on f.id = b.icon_id
where f.url like '%domain-of-the-site%'
```

Column `image_data` will contain blob with the icon. You can see preview in the right panel and can save it to file using toolbar above it:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: SQLiteFlow works well too, free on the Mac App Store. Just need to change the `Favicons` file to have a ".db" suffix.